# Is there a way for Data Filtering outside of the "JavaScript Initialization Code"

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-jet

While developing applications with APEX (18.2) technologies, one can provide custom data filter callback for a chart under App Builder -> Advanced -> "JavaScript Initialization Code".  In my case i do it to *compute label values*.
Here is my working solution based on the Example from the Help Page inside the the App Builder:

```
  function( options ){
    // Setup a callback function which gets called when data is retrieved, it allows to manipulate the series
    options.dataFilter = function( data ) {
        series = data.series;
            $.each(series[0].items, function (_i, item) {
              if (item.value) {
                item.label = (Math.round(item.value*100)/100).toString();
                item.labelPosition = 'outsideBarEdge';
              }
            });
        data.series[ 0 ].color = "#00FF00";
        return data;
    };
    return options;
}
```

This function will be called each time the data series for that diagram is changed.
Problem: the **dataFilter callback** is called as long as the chart is initialized, each time the data series changes.

Now, i would like **to call a different callback at a later time** (f.e. from a **dynamic action**) after the area containing this chart was refreshed to manipulate the data in a slightly different manner(irrelevant to the question).

**Is there any way to find out that the data series are completely loaded and the data object is ready for manipulations?**

Thanks in advance. 
P.s. my first question on stackoverflow, hope it is informative enough.

I have tried regularly checking the data.series attribute of the chart and calling my custom data filter function when it is not null. The problem with this solution is (that it is way to dirty..), that a diagram can have two y axes and this solution will start manipulating data as long as data for one y axis is loaded. 
Since i am computing labels - the second data series (for the second y axis) will not have labels.

My dirty solution with regular checks of the data.series should not be the starting point for the new one, hence i decided not to post it.

Expected results: all data series of a chart have precomputed label values for all of its points when a new data filter callback is called for the chart from a dynamic action.

Comment: Hi, I have the same question about executing the Javascript code( the one mentioned in your question) in the dynamic action. Did you find a way to solve that?

Comment: Hi @Coding_Rabbit, sadly nobody answered this and i was not able to find any viable solution. I also posted this question [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4199269) on Oracle Community Apex Forum but to no avail.